# Breakdown of data

Tags: sql

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
            WHEN answer_time IS NOT NULL
                AND A.ent_split IS NOT NULL
                AND call_type NOT LIKE 'PBX%'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS CH
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN answer_time IS NOT NULL
                AND A.ent_split IS NOT NULL
                AND call_type NOT LIKE 'PBX%'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) + SUM(CASE 
            WHEN abandon_time IS NOT NULL
                AND answer_time IS NULL
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS CO
FROM reporting_call_matrix AS A WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE A.CALENDAR_DATE >= '10/01/2015'
    AND A.CALENDAR_DATE <= '4/30/2016'
    AND A.SPLIT IN (
        35
        ,55
        ,73
        )
    AND (A.ent_split IS NOT NULL)
```

Which  in return rolled up all 3 split information to 
 CH  175282 
 CO  209452

My problem is I need the data to show individual fr each one of the split IN

Comment: if you want to see a row of data for each value of `SPLIT`, your query needs to use a `GROUP BY` clause, which i don't see in your query so far.  Have you tried using (or looked into) `GROUP BY`?

Comment: what sql server are you using?

Comment: that worked perfect thanks

Answer (score 1):

"Data for each split" sounds like you need to use `GROUP BY`.  Have you tried something like this?

```
SELECT A.SPLIT, 
     SUM(CASE 
            WHEN answer_time IS NOT NULL
                AND A.ent_split IS NOT NULL
                AND call_type NOT LIKE 'PBX%'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS CH
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN answer_time IS NOT NULL
                AND A.ent_split IS NOT NULL
                AND call_type NOT LIKE 'PBX%'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) + SUM(CASE 
            WHEN abandon_time IS NOT NULL
                AND answer_time IS NULL
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS CO
FROM reporting_call_matrix AS A WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE A.CALENDAR_DATE >= '10/01/2015'
    AND A.CALENDAR_DATE <= '4/30/2016'
    AND A.SPLIT IN (
        35
        ,55
        ,73
        )
    AND (A.ent_split IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY A.SPLIT
ORDER BY A.SPLIT
```

Comment: that is what I was looking for.